# How do I use GridLayout and multiple Panels?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout

How do I use multiple `JPanel` containers to make this code look like this?

This is the image of what my code is supposed to be like but I cant figure it out.
I can only use `GridLayout`, `BorderLayout` and `FlowLayout`. As a beginner, We've only been over basic concepts but I need more help.

I am also not permitted to use `GridBagLayout`. I appreciate all the help.

Comment: Well what have you tried? I don't see any attempt to nest panels. All I see is a single panel with a GridLayout. And why would you use a grid of (6, 1). How does that map to anything in the picture. Start with logical groupings of components. It looks to me like the top row could be a panel using a GridLayout with 3 components. Then you add that to the BorderLayout.PAGE_START of the frame.The next row to me looks like a panel with a GridLayout for 4 components. I'll let you go from there. You learn by trying.

Comment: Thank you!i have this so far but how do I get the buttons to retain their size and the labels to allign with the lists https://pastebin.com/LWxcaFkh

Comment: Post your code in the forum not on an external website. And the code should be posted in the forum of an [mcve]. That is your question is about layout, so the actual data is irrelevant. For the top row all you need is 3 labels of equal size, so you can just use text for now (and add your images later). Same for the JList. You just use setVisibleRowCount(...) and setPrototypeCellValue(...) to give the JList a reasonable size. Then you worry about adding the components to the panels and nesting the panels appropriately.

Comment: `the labels to align with the lists` - if the labels are in a panel using a `GridLayout` then create another panel for the labels the uses a GridLayout. The horizontal size of each cell will be the same. If you want the label centered then you use the `setAlignmentX(...)` method

Comment: Your original requirement stated you could only use FlowLayout, GridLayout and BorderLayout, but I agree, if you can use a BoxLayout then it makes it easier to create panels that can be layered vertically.

Answer (score 3):

A common strategy to solve complex computing tasks, is to break them into small, well defined manageable tasks. Divide and conquer. 
This also applies to gui: break the design into small, easy to layout containers. 
In this case, consider dividing the design into 3 areas (`JPanel`s) nested in a main `JPanel`:

[image]

If you can't use `GridBagLayout`  you can implement bottom panel using `BoxLayout`.
`BoxLayout` is a valid option also for main panel, to allow for different child panels (top, center, bottom) height.

Demo:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Lab1 extends JFrame
{
    public Lab1() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel main = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,1));
        //to allow different child-panels height use BoxLayout
        //BoxLayout boxLayout = new BoxLayout(main, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);

        add(main);
        JPanel top = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,3));
        main.add(top);
        top.add(getPanel(Color.RED));
        top.add(getPanel(Color.GREEN));
        top.add(getPanel(Color.BLUE));

        JPanel center = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,4));
        main.add(center);
        center.add(getPanel(Color.YELLOW));
        center.add(getPanel(Color.CYAN));
        center.add(getPanel(Color.BLACK));
        center.add(getPanel(Color.LIGHT_GRAY));

        JPanel bottom = new JPanel();
        bottom.setLayout(new BoxLayout(bottom, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        main.add(bottom);

        bottom.add(getPanel(Color.PINK));
        JPanel rightPane =  getPanel(Color.MAGENTA);
        rightPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900, 200));
        bottom.add(rightPane);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel getPanel(Color color) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(color);
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
        return panel;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new Lab1();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Do I need to create another panel for the sandwich, side and drink labels?

Comment: "***Do I need to create another panel for the sandwich, side and drink labels ?***" I am not sure what do you mean.   "***how to I change the sizes of the buttons to its original ?*** "  Which buttons ? Please post a new question and include [mcve].  Each post should be about one focused question. Post a message here to inform me that you posted a new question. I'll be glad to help when you do.